# Determine the smallest number $K$ s.t. $f(x,g(x)) \le K$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on the real plane defined by
>
> $$f(x,y)=(2-\cos x)\exp(y)+(2+\cos x)\exp(-y)$$
> for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

Determine the smallest number $K$ for which there exists some differentiable function $g:\mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $   such that $f(x,g(x)) \leq K$ for all real number $x$

All I got was $0 \leq f(x,y) \leq 3\exp(y)+\exp(-y)$. I am not sure how I can proceed further using this result. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For $g(x)=\cos(x)$ you do have $f(x,g(x))\le 4$.

Comment: It seems that $K=4$ is the required $K$. Try to prove or deny this.